# Is RVO enabled by default on gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, return-value-optimization

I am using gcc 6.3 and I'd like to know if my compilation is using Return Value Optimization (RVO) by default. I see that there is an option to disable it (*‑fno‑elide‑constructors*), and I suppose it is enabled by default, **but how can I be sure?** I checked the different levels of optimization that can be done https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options, but I couldn't find the option *‑fno‑elide‑constructors* listed.

Comment: What language standard are you compiling to? i.e C++11, C++14, C++17

Comment: I am using C++14

Comment: It is not listed under optimization options, because it's not an optimization option. It's listed under default [C++ Dialect Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options)